# Bootstrap Carousel Produces "Blank Images"

Tags: image, carousel

My Bootstrap Carousel produces “Blank Images”. Is there something wrong with the html?  Do I need to edit the CSS file? Thanks in advance!

```html
    <div class="row align-items-center my-5">
      <div class="col-lg-7">
        <div id="homeCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
          <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
              <img src="img/900X400.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="" />              
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
              <img src="" class="d-block w-100" alt="" />              
            </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
              <img src="" class="d-block w-100" alt="" />              
            </div>
          </div>
          <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#homeCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
          </a> 
          <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#homeCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove these two blank carousel-items

```
          <div class="carousel-item">
              <img src="" class="d-block w-100" alt="" />              
            </div>
```